# How far were early grenades thrown in the 17th century?

Tags: warfare, 17th-century

Early grenades weighed about three pounds, apparently, and were generally thrown by tall, strong men. I haven't been able to find a figure on how far they were normally thrown, at what range they were considered effective.

Does anyone know how far grenades could be thrown by hand, in the 17th (and early 18th) century?

Comment: Just for reference, modern shot put competitors throw a 16lb shot (i.e. about the same size but 5 times heavier) up to 75ft. This is, however, the result of continued practise and development of their technique.

Comment: @KillingTime: Shot putters do NOT *throw* the shot; they *put* it (from a position couched by the neck and shoulder). This is a very particular action, and quite different, for example, from the *cricket-throw* (a windmill type action) used to throw a grenade. This latter technique is easier to learn, more accurate, does not require spinning, and possibly produces greater distance.

Comment: Run the experiment by throwing a 3 pound stone and see how far it goes?

Comment: I was trained in the army to throw a modern hand grenade (less than a pound) at least 35 meters. I doubt if you can throw a 3 pound grenade that far.

Comment: What if you are using coconuts? Or if your grenade weighs more than a duck?